# MySql Select from colon

Tags: mysql

table: user

```
| user_Id  | my_threads          |               
| 100      | 200:1, 201:2, 217:4 |
| 101      | 200:1, 215:3, 217:4 |
```

Table: thread

```
| thread_id | author_id | title                     |
| 217       | 100       | This is title thread      |
| 200       | 101       | this is only test         |
```

When the user login successfully $userId=user_Id, show title of that user threads?

```
select title 
from thread
where FIND_IN_SET(thread.thread_id,(select my_threads from user where user_id=100));
```

this sql above works when my_threads no colon like this 200, 217

Comment: I don't understand. What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

replace your colon to commas

```
select title 
from thread
where FIND_IN_SET(thread.thread_id,
        (select replace(replace(my_threads,':',','),' ','') from user where user_id=100))
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75dc9/11)

Comment: this sql gives me 2 titles for (200:1) gives me (200 + 1) i only need thread (200).

Comment: @user1710911: Please see the SQL fiddle updated in the answer

Comment: thanks for your help. but as you can see user_id 100 has 2 titles 200+217 sql fiddle gives me only 1